# channel handler did not write message on netty 4.0

Tags: netty

I wrote simple ChannelHandler like this.

```
public class SimpleServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    ctx.write("Welcome to " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() + "!\r\n");
    ctx.write("It is " + new Date() + " now.\r\n");
    ctx.flush();
}

@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {

}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    ctx.writeAndFlush("=>complete");
    System.out.println("complete");
};

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    // Close the connection when an exception is raised.
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
}
```

}

This handler works show welcome message if client(telnet) connect to server. And show complete message if read complete.
I try to connect server but any message response from server(but I confirmed system log).

I can't understand why.

P.S : I attach code how boot server

```
public class SimpleServer {

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup);
        b.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
        b.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new SimpleServerHandler());
            }
        });
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128);
        b.childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

        ChannelFuture f = b.bind("127.0.0.1", 8080).sync();
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you write a String you need to put a StringEncoder in the ChannelPipeline. If you add a ChannelFutureListener to the ChannelFuture that was returned by the write(...) you will see an error .

Comment: Thank you. You're right. I fixed it use StringEncoder. Also, I could convert String to byte array.